# Design transparent activity on top of other activity

Tags: android, android-layout

How to approach to this design. 
want to design the viewpager activity on top of other activity. It should be have blackish scream background. 
Below Screenshot is similar to my requirements. 
[image]

Comment: Did you try transparent background of viewpager and parent layout of activity?

Comment: This can be possible with view pager inside Dialog with circular indicater.

Comment: So what is the issue bro

Answer (score 2):

Option 1. Make a normal `Activity` and set its `Theme` as

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Option 2. Make an `Activity` whose `onCreate` method is just showing a `Dialog` and then set the theme to be:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation of the layout you require.

Yo need to keep in mind that parent layout of activity has transparent black background,
fragment child of view pager and view pager has transparent background.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cb000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@color/colorRed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```